# jQuery Mobile show native select menu on a button click event

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to open up a native select menu on mobile device with a button click event? There can be a hidden select menu if needed.

I am aware that there maybe other ways such as using a panel widget. Just wondering if this approach is possible and anyone did it before.

Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/8fkg0vpu/8/

```js
$('#needToOpenANativeSelectMenu').click(function(){
 //what to do to open up a native select menu?
});
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="panelAdminPage" data-theme="a" backPageId="">
    <!-header-->
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
         <h5 id="papHeader">Example Menu</h5>
        <a id="needToOpenANativeSelectMenu" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all"></a>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">
        <h2>Is is possible to open up a native select menu on mobile device like what the "Example Menu" does with a button (button on the top right corner)?</h2>
        <label for ="selectMenu">Example Menu:</label>
        <select id="selectMenu">
            <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="op3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do using [***trigger()***](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) in device.

```
$('#needToOpenANativeSelectMenu').click(function(){ 
     $('#selectMenu').trigger('focus');  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Also, it might be a good idea to hide the $('#selectMenu') by moving it off screen: $('#selectMenu').parent().css({position:'absolute',top:'-1000px'}); - Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pengyanb/8fkg0vpu/24/.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for digging up old posts, but this solution didn't work for me. In my Android 5.1 chrome browser, clicking the button DOES focus the select (i.e. it gets an orange border) but doesn't open the native select. Any idea as to why and how I can fix this possibly?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that works for me is

```
function openSelect(select) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        select[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        select[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}
```

but it's limited to Safari and Chrome, unfortunately. I've checked it with Android 6.0.1.